# Github forking conundrum

Tags: git, github, git-fork

My problem: I'm taking advice from people who do not use the command line but who use GUIs and this advice seems to be wrong. But perhaps someone here can verify that it is.

The person who advocates forking has said my workflow needs to be this:

1. clone from the main repo
2. create a branch and make changes and check them in
3. somehow push to my fork of the repo -- not to the main repo
4. create a pull request from my fork

Is this a normal workflow? Are there commands to do these things? Step 3 makes no sense because when I look at .git/config, I see no mention of my fork. So I cannot push. ***How do I add my fork?*** The upstream is the main repo, the origin is the main repo.

Comment: Yeah, that's standard. Step 3 is necessary because you wouldn't have push permissions on the main.

Comment: But when I look at .git/config, I see no mention of my fork. So I cannot push. How do I add my fork?

Comment: Have you forked it on GitHub? It would be ideal to clone from the fork to begin with, since then the upstream would be set.

Comment: I have tried cloning from my fork, but that leads to catastrophe because my fork always gets behind 100 commits and trying to resolve those always proves impossible.

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to rebase periodically!

Comment: Rebase? At my last job we did rebasing all the time and we frequently discovered days worth of work had gone missing. Rebasing is the git equivalent of smoking: It is very unhealthy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is not interested in solutions that work.

Comment: At $work, we rebase regularly. But we mostly don't use GUIs and our team includes me, so ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal, and doesn't depend much on a GUI vs. command line dichotomy. It is sometimes known as a *triangular workflow*:

1. Fork a repository on Github from the main repo.
2. On your local development machine, clone one of the Github repos (it doesn't matter which), and *configure both of the Github repos as remotes*.
3. Do your work in a branch that you branch off from the main repo. Periodically either rebase or merge (your choice, according to temperament and/or company standards) updates from the main repo into your work.
4. When you're happy with your new feature, push it to your *personal* Github fork, and create a pull request from the branch on your fork to the master repo. Your collaborators can review that and get Github to merge it when all agree it looks good.

With this workflow, the 'master' branch in your personal fork never gets used for anything. I periodically update mine to match the master from the main repo, but that's just for tidiness. You can also delete 'master' on your Github repo completely and declare something else to be the "main branch" there. This works quite okay for many purposes, but I went back to having an explicit master because there was little bits and pieces of our CI automation that it confused.

The end result of this will look just the same as if you synchronize everything both back and forth through our own Github fork, so you can be fully compatible with colleagues who do it that way around.

You can push your working branch to your own Github fork even before you're ready to create a PR. This can be a convenient way to back up your work in case your development machine explodes or you have a brainfart and accidentally `rm -rf` your working directory or recode everything to EBCDIC.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your fork as a "remote" to your repo with this command:

```
git remote add my_fork <URL>
```

`<URL>` is the URL for your forked repository. You can use whatever name you wish instead of `my_fork`.

Alternatively, you can clone directly from your fork and add the main repo as a remote to your local repo.

Comment: I have tried the cloning from my fork option. It resulted in a huge nightmare because my fork got out of date by 100 commits, and nothing that I did could repair that. Imagine having 10 merge errors and upon inspection they are all nonsense like whitespace differences.

Comment: @derik GitHub has some very good documentation about keeping your fork and local copy up to date from the main repo: https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork. This doc assumes that you originally cloned from your fork.